# Apache Solr Query Parse Error during data import when using SolrEntityProcessor

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, dih, solr5

When I try to do import of schooLocationDetails solr core, I get below error . Using Solr 5.3.1

Exception while processing: opportunityDetails document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://:<solr_pwd>@<solr_server>:<solr_port>/solr/locationCore: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'locationId:': Encountered "" at line 1, column 22.

Below is my data-config.xml for the solr core schooLocationDetails.

```
<dataConfig>
<document>
<entity name="school" dataSource="datasource" query="select * from school_table" transformer="RegexTransformer">
<field column="recordKey" name="recordKey" />
<field column="name" name="name" /> 
<field column="location" name="location" /> 
<field column="title" name="title" />   
</entity>
<entity name="locationDetail" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://<solr-user>:<solr_pwd>@<solr_server>:<solr_port>/solr/locationCore" query="locationId:${school.location}" 
fl="*,old_version:_version_">

<field column="locationId" name="locationId" />
<field column="city" name="city" />
<field column="state" name="state" />
<field column="old_version" name="old_version" />
</entity>       
</document>  
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: The `school.location` value is empty. Why that's the case is hard to say without your complete file, but I'm guessing since you don't have the lower `<entity>` as a child of the other entity, it doesn't have access to the values retrieved in your primary query.

Comment: Hi just updated the code.. it was not formatted well

Comment: The issue I mentioned is still present - I'm not sure you'll be able to access the value from the other entity when your SolrEntityProcessor is not a sub-entity of the one you want to reference. You can add a log transformer to your entity to log what data is available (and it seems you have a unused regextransformer defined).

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh. This is resolved after I added SolrEntityProcessor as child entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the entity referencing the value *inside* the other entity. When they're two separate entities, they can't reference each other values (and they'll be imported after each other instead).

```
<entity name="school" dataSource="datasource" query="select * from school_table" transformer="RegexTransformer">
    <field column="recordKey" name="recordKey" />
    <field column="name" name="name" /> 
    <field column="location" name="location" /> 
    <field column="title" name="title" />   

    <entity name="locationDetail" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="" query="locationId:${school.location}" 
  fl="*,old_version:_version_">
        <field column="locationId" name="locationId" />
        <field column="city" name="city" />
        <field column="state" name="state" />
        <field column="old_version" name="old_version" />
    </entity> 
</entity>
```